# What does the double question mark means at the end of the type?

Tags: arrays, swift

I've faced an unknown type in `Show Quick Help` section in Playground.

I've opened `Show Quick Help` section to look at the type of `first` which is the property of the `Array`.

The question is, what is the double marks at the end of the type?

---

*This is familiar*

```swift
Double?
```

[Apple - Optional](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional)

---

**Unknown type**

```swift
Double??
```

[image: screen-shot]

Comment: You should learn about optionals, they're a core feature of Swift, and pretty non-negotiable.

Comment: What type did you expect `item.first` to have? (keeping in mind that `item` has type `[Double?]`, a.k.a. `Array<Optional<Double>>`)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Double??` is shorthand notation for `Optional<Optional<Double>>`, which is simply a nested `Optional`. `Optional` is a generic `enum`, whose `Wrapped` value can actually be another `Optional` and hence you can create nested `Optional`s.

```
let optional = Optional.some(2)
let nestedOptional = Optional.some(optional)
```

The type of `nestedOptional` here is `Int??`.

For your specific example, `item.first` is `Double??`, since `item` itself is of type `[Double?]` and `Array.first` also returns an `Optional`, hence you get a nested `Optional`.

Your `compactMap` call on `data` achieves nothing, since you call it on the outer-array, whose elements are non-optional arrays themselves. To filter out the `nil` elements from the nested arrays, you need to `map` over `data` and then call `compactMap` inside the `map`.

```
let nonNilData = data.map { $0.compactMap { $0 } } // [[100, 35.6], [110, 42.56], [120, 48.4], [200]]
```

Comment: I don't have enough to add to this answer to warrant making my own separate answer, but I would suggest mentioning that a "nested optional" means `Optional<Optional<Double>>`, and talk about why `first` adds a layer of optionality